# Parse out numbers from multiple String fields, add them to a new field in MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to come up with a way to parse out the "numbers" in three different fields of type `string`, convert them to true number types, and add them together into a new field. I have to do this in an aggregation pipeline, so that when my documents get to the "group" stage that I'm putting after, I can create a sum of ALL of the documents' item1, item2, and item3 fields.

The collection has objects like:

```
{
    "groupId": 1,
    "item1": "$300.00 - Jason"
    "item2": "$25.50 - Stephanie"
    "item3": ""
}
```

There will always be three items in every document, but not every item will have something in it.

After the operation in the aggregation pipeline, I am hoping to get a document like this:

```
{
    "groupId": 1,
    "itemTotal": 325.5
}
```

The next stage in the pipeline will be to group documents by groupId, getting the itemTotal for the group (I can handle that, as it will be simple at that point).

The first thing I tried is $regexFind but it looks like I can only run that on one field at a time, and I am hoping I can parse out all three numbers and add them in one step. The only path forward that I know of would be to do something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            item1NumberString: { $regexFind: {input: "item1", regex: /\$(\d{1,}\.\d\d)/} },
            item2NumberString: { $regexFind: {input: "item2", regex: /\$(\d{1,}\.\d\d)/} },
            item3NumberString: { $regexFind: {input: "item3", regex: /\$(\d{1,}\.\d\d)/} }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "itemTotal": {$add: [
                {$toInt: "$item1NumberString.captures.0"}, 
                {$toInt: "$item2NumberString.captures.0"}, 
                {$toInt: "item3NumberString.captures.0"} 
            ] } 
        }
    }
]);
```

But it seems inefficient to break it out into multiple pipeline stages if that's not necessary. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this? Maybe by creatively using a concatenate operator or something?

**I will need to convert this answer to a Spring MongoDB query as well**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat following steps for 3 fields:

1. split by `-` and get first token / part
2. remove dollar sign
3. `$convert` to change the string to double

Then sum up the 3 parsed doubles.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      // split by - and get first token
      item1Parsed: {
        $first: {
          "$split": [
            "$item1",
            " - "
          ]
        }
      },
      item2Parsed: {
        $first: {
          "$split": [
            "$item2",
            " - "
          ]
        }
      },
      item3Parsed: {
        $first: {
          "$split": [
            "$item3",
            " - "
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      // remove dollar sign
      "item1Parsed": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$item1Parsed",
          "find": {
            $literal: "$"
          },
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "item2Parsed": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$item2Parsed",
          "find": {
            $literal: "$"
          },
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "item3Parsed": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$item3Parsed",
          "find": {
            $literal: "$"
          },
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      // parse to double
      item1Parsed: {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$item1Parsed",
          "to": "double",
          "onError": 0.0
        }
      },
      item2Parsed: {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$item2Parsed",
          "to": "double",
          "onError": 0.0
        }
      },
      item3Parsed: {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$item3Parsed",
          "to": "double",
          "onError": 0.0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      // sum them up
      groupId: 1,
      itemTotal: {
        $sum: [
          "$item1Parsed",
          "$item2Parsed",
          "$item3Parsed"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lbFCubQfOTj)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this actually looks like it's significantly more complicated than the over-complicated sample pipeline I provided in my question.

Comment: @rook218 It could be subjective when you describe something as over-complicated if you do not define what is complexity beforehand. Someone may argue the usage of regex is complex since it could be non-intuitive to people other than the regex author. Nevertheless, you can resort to `$regexFind` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DmbjVkmas2G), but with the same token extraction - double parsing process, the code is unlikely to be shorter / "simpler".

Comment: Thank you! I mentioned in my question that I was hoping for a way to do this in one operation, but you're convincing me that it's not really possible. Thank you for your input and for talking me through it!